# How to be able to find / replace whatever content is on a certain line in several pages when the content in the pages is not the same for that line?

Tags: excel, batch-file, notepad++

I need a script, bat, or even done in NOTEPAD++ or MS Exel with a plugin or etc.

Let's say I have multiple pages opened in NOTEPAD++ or in a sub-folder in Windows.

**As an example:**

All the pages have 5 LINES each. -- **NOTE**: the `LINE #:` examples below represent what NOTEPAD++ tells me when I enabled the LINE feature -- like also what GITHUB does, it gives each line in a page a number.  So the pages I am working on, don't really have `LINE #:` in the pages.

To make it easy to understand, let's say I have three (3) pages. And here are the contents of each page. **NOTE**: in reality, I have a few dozen pages I need to edit, but for this example, we'll stick to 3 pages.

**PAGE 1:**

```
LINE 1: Black
LINE 2: Blue
LINE 3: Yellow
LINE 4: Brown
LINE 5: Purple
```

**PAGE 2:**

```
LINE 1: Dog
LINE 2: Cat
LINE 3: Goldfish
LINE 4: Parrot
LINE 5: Horse
```

**PAGE 3:**

```
LINE 1: Roses
LINE 2: Iris
LINE 3: Gullies
LINE 4: Pandoras
LINE 5: Daisies
```

Now then, no matter the content in each line above, I want to be able to do the following.

I want to replace **LINE 3** for all the above pages to say:

```
LINE 3: Carrot
```

And I want to do this in a mass way, so I don't have to view each page and edit it myself manually.  In other words, be able to find/replace whatever content is on a certain line in the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I found a solution, I can do this with MS Excel.  I followed the guide [found here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010653_Editing_the_Same_Cell_in_Multiple_Sheets.html), did a test, and it worked.

I'd still be very interested if there is another way, like doing it with NOTEPAD++ or a batch file.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.